# AWS API Gateway Change Content Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, twilio, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm hoping someone can help, I've got AWS Lambda returning some XML in `context.succeed` or `context.fail` everything is excellent apart from one small part.   echo out the XML, but because the header still has `Content-Type: application/json` and the Twilio server I'm talking too is looking at this and rejecting it even though the body is actually valid XML.

Is there a way to override the header?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look in the API Gateway console and select the method in question, you should see a section titled *Method Response* on the right side.  If you select that you should see the various response codes and you can add one or select an existing one and change the `Content-Type` associated with that response.

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway doesn't currently support binary data. You can, however, return base64 encoded data from your Integration Layer (Lambda). Then in API Gateway you can use an Integration Response to decode it to binary:

```
($util.base64Decode())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the first result when searching for setting the mimetype for the AWS API Gateway, as I was struggling to figure out how to get the client to download a PDF sent by a Lambda function using an HTTP API Gateway.

I ended up solving it by setting up the route with integration I wanted on the HTTP API Gateway, editing the "Parameter Mapping", and setting it to "Response status code". With a "Response key" of 200, I could modify `header.Content-Type` with Modification type `Overwrite` and setting the value to `application/pdf`

[image: Screenshot from AWS API Gateway's console, showing what settings to put in as described above]